# How to connect to a Windows PC?

Tags: network, windows, sharing, smb

I've tried to connect my MacBook to my Windows 10 PC via SMB without success.

1. My Windows PC is in a private network and I shared a folder readable by Everyone. One time I found the Windows PC on my MacBook, but couldn't connect as Guest. Now I can't even find it.

I would like to reliably find the Windows PC on my MacBook and connect to it as Guest.

2. I've activated File Sharing on my MacBook and shared the Public folder 'Write Only (Drop Box)' to Everyone. My MacBook doesn't show up in Network on the Windows PC, but when I enter the address it tries to connect, asking me for network credentials.

I would like my MacBook to show up in Windows Network and connect to it without credentials (as Guest).

The MacBook is running Big Sur, 11.0.1. The Windows PC seems to be up to date, no pending updates. The MacBook is connected via Wifi, the PC via Ethernet; both to the same router.

Comment: What operating system is the MacBook using? What is the version of the operating system? How are both machines connected to the network (ethernet, WIFI or some other way)?

Comment: Are you trying to access the PC *from* the Mac or vice-versa? It can be done but the first time you connect from a Mac use an IP address: smb://192.168.1.x/SHARENAME. When it asks for a username and password give it a username on the PC that has rights to that share prefixed with the PC name, like this:  pcname\username and then the password of that account *on the pc.* I do that reliably on my home network all the time.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: I've updated my question with the requested details.

Comment: @SteveChambers: I'm trying both. The shares grant access to Everyone, I assume this means I should be able to connect without credentials. Or are you saying this doesn't work in any case (without credentials)? What does 'Everyone' mean in this case?

Comment: I have had issues with connecting as guest and using the everyone account. I always create an account that I can use for sharing with a simple username and password. And that seems to keep the two different operating systems happy (or happier, at least) and has made connecting the two more reliable.